# Enforce case sensitivity in Spring resource resolution

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot application where `/css/StYLE.cSS` will retrieve the css file located in `static/css/style.css`. Once packaged as a war and deployed to Tomcat, however, the urls become case sensitive and the include 404s.

**Is there a way to enforce resource url case sensitivity in Spring MVC / Spring Boot?**

It'd be easier to notice a case mismatch in development if the url 404's than by just being cautious.

Comment: This is typically relegated to the underlying file system.  If you're running on windows vs. Linux or some other case sensitive os, you'll see this behaviour

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're using an OS such as Windows where the filesystem is case-insensitive. In such cases, when you run during development, resources are served from the local folder on disk (which is case insensitive) but when you package up a JAR they are are served against the JAR zip file entries (which are case sensitive).

One option might be to plug in your own `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver` and override `getResource` to make all `resourcePath` arguments lowercase. You'd then also need to enforce that all files under `/static` are lowercase (perhaps you could do this a build time). Alternatively, you might be able to check that the name of any found resource exactly matches the `resourcePath` to effectively make the filesystem version case-sensitive.